# Internal data structure used by JDK for class TreeMap

Tags: jvm, java

I know that Red-Black Trees are used for TreeSet.

I'm wondering what is data structure used for TreeMap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

treeset uses treemap internally, so red black tree only

check javadoc for details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html